# Can you dye Achilles's outfit?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I want to know if you can dye Achilles's outfit by either crafting dyes at the manor or going to the general stores.

Answer (score 2):

Only the basic assassin robes can be dyed.  Additionally, the manor's 'dyes' item is simply a trade item, and cannot be used on the robes.  All alternative color schemes are bought from general stores.